# Entering a Changing Class Object into a List for Python

Tags: python, list, class, object, pickle

I'm trying to make a program that creates objects from another class I made and calls the class methods based on user input.  The problem I'm having is that once a object is created I'm trying to enter that object into a dictionary, so I can compress it with pickle for later use.  I'm having trouble trying to find the best way to append these class objects into a list when the name for the created objects are the same as the name variable I prompt from the user.  The lines I am talking about are lines 34 to 41.  I have so far change it to set the object named personObject to create a object and repeat if another user is created.  It seems to work, I just feel there is a better way.

```
    from budgetaccount import *
    import pickle
    import sys

    class mainprogram:
        def __init__(self):
            self.account_list = {}
            self.name = ""


    def main(self):
        grab_user()
        endProgram = 0
        while endProgram != 6:
            print('Welcome to our monthly budget program\n')
            print('1-Create a new account')
            print('2-Exit')
            selection = input("Enter your Selection: ")
            if selection != "":
                choice = int(selection)
                if choice == 1:
                    self.create_user()
                if choice == 2:
                    break
                continue

        name = self.account_list[0]
        name.showSetBudgetLimits()
    def create_user(self):
        cancel = False

        while (True):
            self.name = input("Type your username: ")
            name = self.name
            income = float(input("Enter your income: "))
            personObject = BudgetAccount(name, income)
            personObject.setUserExspenseLimit()
            self.account_list.append({
            "%s"% (name) : personObject 
            })
            cont = input("Want to add another? (Y/N)")
            if cont == "N":
                break
            continue
        print(self.account_list)
        self.pickle_data1()

    def pickle_data1(self): ###Pickle writes to userdata1.pickle from account_list###
        pickle_out = open("userdata1.pickle", "wb")
        pickle.dump(self.account_list, pickle_out)
        pickle_out.close()


def grab_user():
    pickle_in = open("E:/Python/Lib/idlelib/userdata1.pickle","rb")
    account_list = pickle.load(pickle_in)
    print(account_list)
    print(account_list)

test = ihateThis()
test.main()
```